# Executor Service execution is just running the first thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, executorservice

I'm doing a program in Java that simulates the Token-Ring algorithm.
I have many Jugador objects that compete themselves for the shared resource Balon.
When i want to execute the multiple threads created using ExecutorService, it seems that just the first thread is running and as the **run method** overwritten is a infinte loop, the program keeps in that loop forever.

In the console i just execute the first loop and then the programs just keeps in the infinite loop.

Class Jugador:

```
public class Jugador implements Runnable{
    private Boolean testimonio;
    private Balon balon;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void darPataditas(){
        this.balon.aumentarPataditas();        
    }

    public void recibirTestimonio(){
        System.out.println(this.getNombre() + ", deseas recibir el testimonio (1/0)");
        int rpta = sc.nextInt();
        if(rpta == 1)   this.testimonio = true;
        else
            this.pasarTestimonio();
    }

    public void  pasarTestimonio(){
        this.testimonio = false;
        System.out.println("Yo, "+this.getNombre()+ ", estoy pasando el testimonio a "+ this.getSiguiente().getNombre());
        this.siguiente.recibirTestimonio();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try{
            while(true){
                if(this.testimonio && this.balon.tomarBalon()){
                    this.darPataditas();
                    this.balon.dejarBalon();
                    this.pasarTestimonio();
                    System.out.print(this.getNombre() + ", ¿seguiras jugando?(1/0)");
                    if(sc.nextInt() == 0){
                        this.anterior.setSiguiente(this.siguiente);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Class Balon:

```
public class Balon {
    private int pataditas;
    Lock up = new ReentrantLock();

    public Balon() {
        this.pataditas = 0;
    }

    public void aumentarPataditas(){
        pataditas++;
    }

    public boolean tomarBalon(){
        if(up.tryLock()) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public void dejarBalon(){
        up.unlock();
    }
}
```

Main Class:

```
public class TokenRing {

    private static final int NUM_JUGADORES = 5;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        Jugador[] jugadores = null;
        Balon pelota = new Balon();
        jugadores = new Jugador[NUM_JUGADORES];
        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_JUGADORES; i++){
            System.out.print("Ingrese nombre del jugador: ");
            String name = sc.next();
            jugadores[i] = new Jugador(name, i+1, pelota);
        }
 
           jugadores[0].setTestimonio(true);
        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_JUGADORES-1; i++){
            jugadores[i].setSiguiente(jugadores[i+1]);
            jugadores[i+1].setAnterior(jugadores[i]);
        }
        jugadores[NUM_JUGADORES-1].setSiguiente(jugadores[0]);
        jugadores[0].setAnterior(jugadores[NUM_JUGADORES-1]);
   
        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_JUGADORES);
        try{
            for(int i = 0; i < NUM_JUGADORES; i++){
                threadPool.execute(jugadores[i]);
            }
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }finally{
            threadPool.shutdown();

            while (!threadPool.isTerminated()) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            System.out.println("El balon dio " + pelota.getPataditas() + " pataditas.");
        }

    }
}
```

You could take a look of the full code my [Github Repository](https://github.com/Oberyn18/Token-Ring-Simulation)
Thanks a lot.

Comment: i dont see a code line where you set the testimonio flag to true for other runnables than the first. There are some other problems with the code like multiple Scanners on stdin and missing synchronization.

Comment: Oh, i've assigned testimonio to true above in the main class. Could you plz tell me what the problem is with multiple scanners and what "missing synchronization" is?

Comment: Post your code (as [mcve] - meaning the relevant and running code) as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: Now i've added the code as text. Please take a look on it.

Comment: All of your threads have a `new Scanner(System.in);`?  That's a really bad pattern @Oberyn that is going to have undefined results.  You should have the main thread read in the ints and create the `jugadores` with the integer.  Not sure if that's your problem however.